# export <td> with two lines to pdf using itextsharp

Tags: itext, html-table

I am having trouble exporting to pdf if I have a two lines in a td. Can you please advise. the code is as follows:

```
        .style7
       {
        font-weight: bold; 
        display:block; 
       }
       .style8
       {
         font-size: smaller; 
       }
    </style>



</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlPerson" runat="server" style="margin-right: 3px" Width="1045px">
    <div class="style3"><strong>MAINTENANCE ENGINEERING CALL (MEC)</strong></div>
    <table border="1" 
            style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; width: 1048px; height: 390px;">
   <tr>
   <td><span class="style7">Shop Submittal Date</span>
   <span="style8"><asp:TextBox ID="Sdate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></span>
   </td>
   </tr>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you using XML Worker (if so, which version) or `HTMLWorker` (deprecated, doesn't support your requirement).

Comment: Please remember that iTextSharp has zero knowledge of ASP.Net things like "panels" and "textbox", it only cares about HTML, so the code that you've posted above doesn't really help us. Render your page to HTML and post that and we might be able to help you more. Also, please explain "trouble". Does it crash? Does it look weird? Does it run slow?

Comment: Thank you Bruno. Yes I am using HTMLWorker. I will look around for examples to use XML Worker. I appreciate if you can give me an example if you can. Rgds, Suma.

Comment: Thank you Chris. I am having a button to export html page into PDF. and I am getting error, that sdate needs a form tag. My code is as follows: Protected Sub btnExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MEC.pdf")
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Dim sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

Comment: pnlPerson.RenderControl(hw)
        Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())
        Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 100.0F, 0.0F)
        Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
        pdfDoc.Open()
        htmlparser.Parse(sr)
        pdfDoc.Close()
        Response.Write(pdfDoc)
        Response.[End]()

    End Sub

Comment: @user1663368, please use the edit button on your original post to add/update any code samples.